# Facebook API and Invites - tracking accepted invites

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to track what friends and/or how many accept your invite to an app in Facebook?

I'm working on a project where we want to say that a user is Silver status if they get 5 friends to sign up and Gold status if they get 10 friends to sign up. Is their a way to do this through the API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send a personalized URL to Facebook friends from external website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890903/send-a-personalized-url-to-facebook-friends-from-external-website)

Comment: ifaour, any experience with this? Does that seem like the right approach? Or is there something built-in to the API?

Comment: Hi brun.. did you get any success on this??